# why angular 2 is not available in minified distribution?

Tags: angular

angular 1 is available on angular site in min distribution. I am not able to find same for angular 2.
Is it because angular 2 is not released for production?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Angular 2` should be bundled with a module bundle like `webPack`, to allow for minification alongside your own application.

So both `Angular` and your `app` will be bundled together (and minified after) with `webPack`.

You can read more about `webPack` [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

It's also worth mentioning that you can pack `Angular 2` with other things like [SystemJS](https://school.scotch.io/getting-started-with-angular-2/systemjs)